# Calling a function with another function as an argument raises an error

Tags: julia

I have a function that expects another function as an argument but when I call the first function by passing the second function it raises an error

```
using Random: RandomDevice, randstring

alphabet = "_-0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
size = 21

function generate(byte_gen::Function, alphabet::String=alphabet, size::Int64=size)::String
    len = length(alphabet)

    mask = 1
    if len > 1
        mask = 2 << log(2, (len-1)) - 1       
    end

    step = ceil((1.6 * mask * size) / len)

    id = ""
    while true
        bytes = byte_gen(size)

        for i = 0:(step-1)
            byte = bytes[i] & mask
            if alphabet[i]
                id += alphabet[i]
                if length(id) == size
                    return id
                end
            end
        end
    end
end


function randBytestring(size::Int64)::String
    rs = randstring(RandomDevice(), 'a':'z', size)
    ba = Vector{UInt8}(rs)
    return join([join(("\\x", split(repr(cu), "x")[2]), "") for cu in ba], "")
end


generate(randBytestring)
```

I get this traceback

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching <<(::Int64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  <<(::Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, !Matched::Union{UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}) at int.jl:443
  <<(::Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, !Matched::Int64) at int.jl:450
  <<(::Integer, !Matched::Unsigned) at operators.jl:568
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] generate(::typeof(randBytestring), ::String, ::Int64) at /home/palash25/Dev/julia/nano.jl:11
 [2] generate(::Function, ::String) at /home/palash25/Dev/julia/nano.jl:7 (repeats 2 times)
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [7] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:267
 [8] _start() at ./client.jl:436
in expression starting at /home/palash25/Dev/julia/nano.jl:40
```

When I change my function signature to this and call it again I get another error `generate(byte_gen::Function, alphabet::String=alphabet, size::Int64=size)::String`

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching <<(::Int64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  <<(::Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, !Matched::Union{UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}) at int.jl:443
  <<(::Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, !Matched::Int64) at int.jl:450
  <<(::Integer, !Matched::Unsigned) at operators.jl:568
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] generate(::typeof(randBytestring), ::String, ::Int64) at /home/palash25/Dev/julia/nano.jl:11
 [2] generate(::Function, ::String) at /home/palash25/Dev/julia/nano.jl:7 (repeats 2 times)
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [7] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:267
 [8] _start() at ./client.jl:436
in expression starting at /home/palash25/Dev/julia/nano.jl:40
```

UPDATE: I have edit the code snippets to include all of my code so that the example is runnable now.

Comment: Please include a complete, runnable example that reproduces problem. The error message says that there is a problem with a call to `<<`, but you have excluded that code. What is `size`? What is `alphabet`? Also, `//` is not the comment character, `#` is, this just causes more confusion.

Comment: @DNF edited the post, please take a look.

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong: you cannot use `<<` with a float. `log(2, len-1)` is a float, so you need to make it into an integer. Use `ceil(Int, x)` (or round or floor or whatever is appropriate). You will also get a problem with `step` on the next line, even though you `ceil` it, it's still a float and will fail when used for indexing. Use `ceil(Int, ...)` instead.

Comment: But, why do you think this has anything to do with passing a function as an argument? And what are the differences between your two examples and tracebacks? They look identical to me?